# Cannot connect to my own dedicated Gmod server

Tags: server-administration, garrys-mod, ubuntu

I can open the console in Gmod and use the command `connect` to try to join "localhost", "127.0.0.1", and "{my_ip_address}". However, these all show me a dialog box that says "Connection failed after 4 retries".

I have my server installed on Ubuntu 13.04. I wrote a little startup script to optionally update the server and then call this line:

```
./$GMOD_DIR/srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers $MAX_PLAYERS +map $MAP
```

Where `$GMOD_DIR` is `${SERVER}/gmod/`, `$MAX_PLAYERS` is 4, and `$MAP` is `gm_construct`.

It gives me this output:

```
Auto detecting CPU
Using default binary: ./srcds_linux
Server will auto-restart if there is a crash.

Console initialized.
ConVarRef mat_dxlevel doesn't point to an existing ConVar
Game_srv.so loaded for "Garry's Mod"
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 4000
Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
Logging into anonymous gameserver account.
Fetching Workshop Addons.. No -authkey
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
Unable to persist cache 'modelsounds.cache', check file permissions
Error loading cfg/trusted_keys_base.txt
Error loading cfg/pure_server_minimal.txt
PREP OK
Lua JIT is DISABLED!
ConVarRef room_type doesn't point to an existing ConVar
Executing dedicated server config file server.cfg
Map cycle file 'cfg/mapcycle.txt' was not found.
Unable to persist cache 'modelsounds.cache', check file permissions
Nav File is wrong or something (4)
Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
Logging into anonymous gameserver account.
Server logging enabled.
Unable to open logfiles under logs/L0714
Logging disabled
Connection to Steam servers successful.
   Public IP is (omitted).
Assigned anonymous gameserver Steam ID [A-1:3885134849(3517)].
VAC secure mode is activated.
```

---

I am mostly concerned with these lines:

```
Lua JIT is DISABLED!
```

I'm assuming this is some reference to Lua/Java Just In Time compiler

```
Nav File is wrong or something (4)
```

No idea what this is. Google didn't help very much.

```
Server logging enabled.
Unable to open logfiles under logs/L0714
Logging disabled
```

Comment: For LuaJIT, try this: http://www.facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1167102
However, I had that error on my old GMod server and it didn't have any problems running.

Unable to open logfiles might be if you haven't set read permissions or so.

Nav File is wrong or something is most likely just a map that misses a Nav file.

Also, it seems to be setting itself at IP 127.0.1.1, and not 127.0.0.1 (which might be why you can't connect to that one)

Try use "status" in the console.

Edit: crap, thought enter would work for new lines. q_q

Answer (score 1):

Add `+ip 192.168.x.x` to the line that starts the server in the script. Change `192.168.x.x` to whatever the server's internal IP address is, as this is just an example. This can be found by typing `ifconfig` in Terminal. This shouldn't matter when trying to connect locally, but gmod might not like connections if a gateway isn't explicitly stated.

Comment: ifconfig is the unix command

Answer (score 1):

The port could have changed to 27016 instead of the default 27015 since you are using 'connect' try going into 'Find Multiplayer Game' then into 'Local Area Network' and find your server there.

Answer (score 1):

Your server has started normally.  <strike>The Lua JIT interpreter might be disabled due to a missing dependency.  Make sure that you have the Lua binary and devel packages off of `apt-get`.</strike>

I run a dedicated Garry's Mod server off of my local computer.  In order to connect to my own server, I needed to use my external IP address to connect.  Try `connect <your external>:27015`.

EDIT: The Lua JIT interpreter is disabled by default on purpose due to FPS issues.  If you want to turn it on, add `-withjit` to your launch command.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged in as root? If not, try using `sudo`.

`sudo ./$GMOD_DIR/srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers $MAX_PLAYERS +map $MAP`

Your worry about Lua JIT is probably nothing. What concerns me is this line:
`Unable to persist cache 'modelsounds.cache', check file permissions`

Given that your script doesn't have permission to use the file, and that you "can't find" files in your `cfg` directory, leads me to believe you need to run this with advanced privileges.

This is analogous to running an app "As Administrator" in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try disable firewall and test if this allows you to connect to server.
If you haven't changed ports it should be this ones.
27015 and 27005
both TCP and UDP